# Why doesn't my ja.lproj show Japanese?

Tags: localization, internationalization, xib

I tried to localize my app to Japanese, I got ja.lproj folder with AboutViewController.xib inside it, but when I run my app in region Japan with Japanese language, it doesn't show Japanese, still only show English, what do I have to do for anything else?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I clean all targets and build again, repeat these process, but I couldn't get what I need, at last, I deleted app on Simulator, now everything is ok, I got what I need, why is so simple, but no expert tell me, I spent whole two days!

Comment: I think this is a bug, because if my users update it, they never delete it before updating, so that they will never view my new UI, is it right?